# Difference/comparison/relation of real-differentiable vs complex-differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Notes:

1. I don't mean like this where you just convert $x$ to $z$: [$\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}$ real differentiable but not complex differentiable at $x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531411/mathrme-1-x2-real-differentiable-but-not-complex-differentiable-at-x-0)
2. I also don't mean holomorphic instead of complex-differentiable.

---

What I recall/understand:

0. If I have $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, $f=u+iv$ with $u,v: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$, then we may view $f$ alternatively as $f=[u,v]$ for $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ with $u,v$ viewed as $u,v: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.
1. The vector function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is defined as *real-differentiable* at a point $(a,b)$ if each component $u,v$ is real differentiable at $(a,b)$.
2. That $u: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is *real-differentiable* at a point $(a,b)$ is defined as this weird thing from James Stewart, Calculus (similar for $v$)

[image]

3. Sufficient condition: That $u: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is real-differentiable a point $(a,b)$ has a sufficient condition from this theorem also from James Stewart, Calculus (similar for $v$)

[image]

which I read for $u$ as

> If $u_x$ and $u_y$ exist *in an open disc containing* $(a,b)$ and are continuous at $(a,b)$, then $u$ is real-differentiable at $(a,b)$.

4. $f$ is defined *complex-differentiable* at $(a,b)$ if $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(a,b)}{(x,y)-(a,b)}$ exists (where of course we have $\frac{(a,b)}{(c,d)} = (e,f)$ s.t. $\frac{a+ib}{c+id} = e+if)$.
5. Sufficient condition: If $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist in an open disc containing $(a,b)$ and are continuous at $(a,b)$ and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann at $(a,b)$, then $f$ is complex-differentiable at $(a,b)$.
6. Necessary condition: If $f$ is complex-differentiable at $(a,b)$, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist at $(a,b)$ and satisfy Cauchy-Riemann at $(a,b)$.
7. $u_x(a,b)$ is defined as $u_x(a,b) := \lim_{x \to a} \frac{u(x,b)-u(a,b)}{x-a}$ (similar for $u_y$ and then similar for $v$), if this exists.
8. $f_x(a,b)$ is defined as $f_x(a,b) := \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x,b)-f(a,b)}{x-a}$, if this exists. (similar for $f_y$)
9. $f_x(a,b)$ exists if and only if $u_x(a,b)$ and $v_x(a,b)$ exist. (similar for $f_y$)

   - 9.1. This is because $\frac{f(x,b)-f(a,b)}{x-a} = [\frac{u(x,b)-u(a,b)}{x-a},\frac{v(x,b)-v(a,b)}{x-a}]$: take limit of both sides.
10. $f_x(a,b)$ is equivalently defined as $f_x(a,b) := u_x(a,b) + iv_x(a,b) = [u_x(a,b), v_x(a,b)]$, if $u_x(a,b)$ and $v_x(a,b)$ exist. (similar for $f_y$)

    - 10.1. This is also because $\frac{f(x,b)-f(a,b)}{x-a} = [\frac{u(x,b)-u(a,b)}{x-a},\frac{v(x,b)-v(a,b)}{x-a}]$: again, take limit of both sides.
11. $u$ differentiable at $(a,b)$ implies $u_x$ and $u_y$ exist at $(a,b)$. Confirmed here: [Questions about real differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289278/questions-about-real-differentiable)

---

Questions:

1. Does $f$ complex-differentiable imply $f$ real-differentiable but not conversely? Why/why not?

   - 1.1. Idea 1.1: That's what it looks like from the sufficient conditions (3) and (5).
   - 1.2. Idea 1.2: If we pretend the sufficient conditions (3) and (5) are also necessary conditions, then obviously real doesn't imply complex because real is missing Cauchy-Riemann. Seems like this is what's going on there: [Do $u$ and $v$ real-differentiable and $u$ and $v$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations hold if and only if $f$ is complex-differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213277/do-u-and-v-real-differentiable-and-u-and-v-satisfy-cauchy-riemann-equati?rq=1).
2. Much of elementary complex analysis talks about how [(complex-)holomorphic is much stronger in complex as compared to real-holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947235/why-does-being-holomorphic-imply-so-much-about-a-function) (real differentiable in an open neighbourhood of $p$). What about complex analogues of real properties like differentiable: **How much stronger is complex-differentiable compared to real-differentiable?** (I also asked [smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267741/properties-of-complex-smooth) and [analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289276/holomorphic-is-much-stronger-than-real-differentiable-in-a-neighbourhood-what-a).)

Comment: About 1. Yes. A function $f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is complex differentiable if and only if the $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ function $(u(x,y), v(x,y))$ is real differentiable and the derivatives satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So being complex differentiable is stronger than being differentiable as a real two-dimensional function (which is of course stronger than the real part being differentiable)

Comment: @Zanzag thanks. you can post as answer (if that's actually correct), but....well that's kind of what I'm talking about in Idea (1.1) and Idea (1.2). anyway how exactly do we prove your statement? i don't think either condition of your statement satisfies the sufficient conditions in (3) or (5) so...I guess it all comes down to thinking about the very definition of real differentiable?

Comment: You can find the full proof in the section "Complex Differentiability" there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Riemann_equations

Comment: And yes, you need to work with the definition of real-differentiable in 3., not with the sufficient conditions.

Comment: @Zanzag thanks for the link! actually what i seem to be reading on wiki is something like (complex differentiable and real differentiable)-if and only if-(cauchy riemann and real differentiable). which of the following is what's going on? A - I'm correct and since complex differentiable implies real differentiable we get therefore your original statement (complex differentiable)-if and only if-(cauchy riemann and real differentiable). B - I'm incorrect since wiki really says the same thing as your original statement C - other. (see next comment)

Comment: @Zanzag this is what wiki says: 'if f : C → C is a function which is differentiable when regarded as a function on R2, then f is complex differentiable if and only if the Cauchy–Riemann equations hold.' so i interpret as like $A \implies (B \iff C)$ and hence $(A \wedge B) \iff (A \wedge C)$ or something

Comment: If $f$ is not real-differentiable, then it can't be complex differentiable. If it is real-differentiable, then it is complex-differentiable if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation. So, in summary, $f$ is $C$-differentiable if and only if it is $\mathbb{R}^2$-differentiable and it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will clarify somewhat: given a function $f:V \to W$, where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional $\mathbf{R}$-vector spaces, we say $f$ is *differentiable* at $v \in V$ if there is a linear map $L:V \to W$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(v+h)-f(v)-L(h)}{|h|}=0,$$ and we call $L$ (which is unique if it exists) the *derivative* of $f$ at $v \in V$.

Exactly the same definition works if one simply replaces $\mathbf{R}$ by $\mathbf{C}$ (or indeed by any local field): supposing $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional $\mathbf{C}$-vector spaces and $f:V \to W$ is a function, we say $f$ is $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable at $v \in V$ if there is a $\mathbf{C}$-linear map $L:V \to W$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(v+h)-f(v)-L(h)}{|h|}=0,$$ and we call $L$ the *derivative* of $f$ at $v$ in this case as well. Now a $\mathbf{C}$-linear map is in particular $\mathbf{R}$-linear, and so if we regard complex vector spaces $V$ and $W$ as $\mathbf{R}$-vector spaces by forgetting their complex structure, such a map is differentiable with derivative $L$. Conversely, if it is differentiable (in the real sense) then it is $\mathbf{C}$-differentiable *exactly if its derivative $L$ is $\mathbf{C}$-linear*. If you unwind this in case $V=W=\mathbf{C}$ you get precisely the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! This settles Q1. That leaves Q2...

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not real-differentiable, then it can't be complex differentiable. If it is real-differentiable, then it is complex-differentiable if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation. So, in summary, $f$ is $C$-differentiable if and only if it is $\mathbb{R}^2$-differentiable and it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks Zanzag ! This settles Q1. That leaves Q2...